# How to send object data through $POST from via ajax (from jQuery to vanilla JS)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have this jQuery snippet I was using to send form data through an ajax request and have the php spit out some more jQuery to show a email was sent. I have most of the code down put I wont get a response through, no mail, no js error, and no php error.

Here is my html form:

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post">
  <label for="required_question" style="position:absolute; left:-10000px; bottom:auto; width:1px; height:1px; overflow:hidden;"></label>
  <label for="required_question2" style="position:absolute; left:-10000px; bottom:auto; width:1px; height:1px; overflow:hidden;"></label>
  <label for="name" style="position:absolute; left:-10000px; bottom:auto; width:1px; height:1px; overflow:hidden;">name</label>
  <label for="email" style="position:absolute; left:-10000px; bottom:auto; width:1px; height:1px; overflow:hidden;">email</label>
  <label for="subject" style="position:absolute; left:-10000px; bottom:auto; width:1px; height:1px; overflow:hidden;">email</label>
  <label for="text" style="position:absolute; left:-10000px; bottom:auto; width:1px; height:1px; overflow:hidden;">message</label>
  <label for="submit" style="position:absolute; left:-10000px; bottom:auto; width:1px; height:1px; overflow:hidden;">submit</label>

  <input tabindex="-1" name="required_question" placeholder="Required..." style="position:absolute; left:-10000px; bottom:auto; width:1px; height:1px; overflow:hidden;"></input>
  <input tabindex="-1" name="required_question2" placeholder="Required..." style="position:absolute; left:-10000px; bottom:auto; width:1px; height:1px; overflow:hidden;"></input>
  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name..." required></input>
  <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email..." required></input>
  <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject..." required></input>
  <textarea name="text" placeholder="Enter your message here" required></textarea>
  <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Submit."></input>
</form>
```

and here is the jquery snippet:

```
$('#contact-form').on('submit', function() {

  $('#submit').val('Sending...');

  var  data = {};

  $(this).find('[name]').each(function(index, value) {
    data[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
  });
  $.post('/dss-assets/PHP/mailer.php', {term: data}).done(function(data) {
    $('body').append(data);
  });
    return false;
});
```

Heres what I have so far in my vanilla js:

```
document.getElementById('contact-form').addEventListener('submit', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]').value = 'Sending...';
  document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]').blur();
  $disabled_inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input, textarea');
  for(i = 0; i < $disabled_inputs.length; i++){
    $disabled_inputs[i].disabled = true;
    $disabled_inputs[i].style.opacity = '.7';
  }

  var $data = {};

  this.querySelectorAll('input[name], textarea[name]').forEach(function($input) {
  $data[$input.getAttribute('name')] = $input.value;
  });
  console.log($data)

  inquriry_request = new XMLHttpRequest();

  inquriry_request.onload = function(){
    document.querySelector('body').append(inquriry_request.responseText)
  }

  inquriry_request.onerrror = function(){
    console.log({contactpage: $data})
  }

  inquriry_request.open('POST', '/dss-assets/PHP/mailer.php', true)
  // ---it seems my data type was wrong and thats why it wouldnt send---
  inquriry_request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data'); 
  inquriry_request.send({contactpage: $data});

});
```

and here is the mailer.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['contactpage'])) {

$array = $_REQUEST['contactpage'];
//------required questions-----------------
$rq = $array['required_question'];
$rqtwo = $array['required_question2'];

if($rq != '' || $rqtwo != ''){
  $quo = '"';
  $input = "$quo input[name*='hmnvr'] $quo";
  echo "<script>
    console.log('uhhohh')
  </script>";
  exit();
};

  //----------sendmail-------------
  $headers = "From: Desert Sun Studio | Sal <sal@desertsunstudio.com>\r\n";
  $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
  $name = $array['name'];
  $email = $array ['email'];
  $subject = $array['subject'];
  $text = $array['text'];

  $msg ='Hello ' . $name .',<br><br>
  Thank you for submitting a message through https://www.desertsunstudio.com. This is just to confirm your message has
  been received, please allow up to 24 hours to receive a response. To follow up or add any additional information
  please <a href="mailto:sal@desertsunstudio.com">click here</a> or simply reply to this email.';

  $msg2= 'Hello sally, this is your lil mail bot:)) Looks like we got a message, lets take a looksie: <br><br>From: ' . $name .
  '<br><br>Contact email: ' . $email . '<br><br> Message: &quot;' . $text . '&quot;';





  if(@mail($email, 'Response to your recent inqury at Desert Sun Studio.', $msg, $headers) && @mail('sal@desertsunstudio.com', 'Looks like we have a potential client!', $msg2, $headers)){
    $quo = '"';
    echo "<script>
      console.log('sent')
    </script>";
    exit();
  } else {

  echo "<script>
    console.log('uhhohh')
  </script>";
  exit();
  }
};

?>
```

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint in your onload handler to see if a response is coming back? Also, your onload handler is just going to append the data you sent to the server, not the data that came back from the server. For that you need to access the XMLHttpRequest object's responseText property from within your handler.

Comment: i changed .append($data) to .append(inquriry_request.responseText); I added the breakpoint and now nothings loading in (you were right about it loading the js object into the body)-haha sorry i am trying to transition from jQuery to vanilla JS and my fundamentals are not as sharp as i had hoped;

Comment: Does that mean your breakpoint isn't being hit, or that it is being hit but there's no data in the responseText property? If you add an error handler to that XMLHttpRequest object, you may also see what is preventing the request from succeeding.

Comment: @DanielArant i had the wrong content-type so i switched it to multipart/form and it started trying to run but would give me these errors appened to the body as a server response "Bad Request Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand. Additionally, a 400 Bad Request error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.". Do you know what I could do to fix it? Also the onerror function does fire and logs the object

Answer (score 1):

try FormData to send the entire form

Example:

```
$('#contact-form').on('submit', function() {
      $('#submit').val('Sending...');
      var data = new FormData(this);
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/dss-assets/PHP/mailer.php',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,    
        data: data,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(res) {
           $('body').append(res)
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("fail");
        }
      });
    });
```

Comment: That's good advice, but I think the question is looking for a vanilla JavaScript answer.

Comment: Yes thank you! my jquery form is already functional, i am trying to translate it to vanilla js